# Consider the series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^{2n+1}}{(n+5)4^{n}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+2)^{2n+1}}{(n+5)4^{n}} $ . Does it converge at $ x=2 $ ?

**Answer:** By D'alembert's test ,  $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty } |\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} |=  |\frac{x+2}{4}| $ . Now  $ | \frac{x+2}{4}| <1  \ \ implies \ \ x <2 $.

When $ x=2 $ , the series becomes $ \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{4^{n+1}}{n+5} $. I think this new  series is divergent. Hence at x=2 , the series does not converges but converges $ at \ (-6, 2) $ . **Am I right ?**

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{(x+2)^2}{4}\right\rvert$$

Comment: It should be $ | \frac{x+2}{4}| $

Comment: Too bad it is not. In point of fact, you may also notice that the series diverges for $x=1$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Ratio does state that a series is absolutely convergent if the limit of adjacent terms is less than one, but when it is equal to one the test is inconclusive. Meaning that more information is needed to tell if it converges. It  clearly diverges at x=2 because all the terms will be greater than 1 when n is greater than 1.